# UICollectionView not rendering all rows

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, rendering, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to create a simple app, where one can enter a number of columns and a number of rows for an UICollectionView. The collection view then calculates the size of possible squares that fit into it and draws them. 
I want to allow a maximum of 32 in width and 64 in height. Scrolling is disabled as the whole grid should be shown at once.

For example, 4x8 looks like this

[image: 4x8 Grid]

and 8x4 will look like this

[image: 8x4 Grid]

So as one can see that works fine. The problems comes with a higher amount of columns and/or rows. Up to 30x8 everything is fine but starting with 31 only 6 of the 8 rows are drawn.

[image: 31x8 Grid]

So I don't understand why. Following is the code I use to calculate everything:

Number of section and number of rows:

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int
{
    let num = Int(heightInput.text!)
    if(num != nil)
    {
        if(num! > 64)
        {
            return 64
        }
        return num!
    }
    return 8
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    let num = Int(widthInput.text!)
    if(num != nil)
    {
        if(num! > 32)
        {
            return 32
        }
        return num!
    }
    return 4
}
```

Cell for item at indexPath

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let size = calculateCellSize()
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    var origin = cell.frame.origin
    origin.x = 1+CGFloat(indexPath.row) + size.width*CGFloat(indexPath.row)
    origin.y = 1+CGFloat(indexPath.section) + size.height*CGFloat(indexPath.section)
    cell.frame = CGRect(origin: origin, size: size)
    NSLog("Cell X:%@, Cell Y:%@",origin.x.description,origin.y.description)
    return cell
}
```

The calculate size method

```
func calculateCellSize() -> CGSize
{
    //First check if we have valid values
    let col = Int(widthInput.text!)
    let row = Int(heightInput.text!)
    if(col == nil || row == nil)
    {
        return CGSize(width: 48.0, height: 48.0)
    }
    //If there are more or equal amount of columns than rows
    let columns = CGFloat(col!)
    let rows = CGFloat(row!)
    if(columns >= rows)
    {
        //Take the grid width
        let gridWidth = drawCollection.bounds.size.width
        //Calculate the width of the "pixels" that fit the width of the grid
        var pixelWidth = gridWidth/columns
        //Remember to substract the inset from the width
        let drawLayout = drawCollection.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        pixelWidth -= (drawLayout?.sectionInset.left)! + 1/columns
        return CGSize(width: pixelWidth, height: pixelWidth)
    }
    else
    {
        //Rows are more than columns
        //Take the grid height as reference here
        let gridHeight = drawCollection.bounds.size.height
        //Calculate the height of the "pixels" that fit the height of the grid
        var pixelHeight = gridHeight/rows
        //Remember to substract the inset from the height
        let drawLayout = drawCollection.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        pixelHeight -= (drawLayout?.sectionInset.top)! + 1/rows
        return CGSize(width: pixelHeight, height: pixelHeight)
    }
    return CGSize(width: 48.0, height: 48.0)
}
```

For debugging reasons I put a counter into the cellforItemAtIndexPath method and in fact I can see that the last two rows are not called. The counter ends at 185 but in theory it should have been called 248 times and in fact the difference will show it is 2*32 - 1(for the uneven 31) so the last missing rows....

Several things came to my mind what the reason is but nothing of it seems to be:

1. the cells are not drawn at the right location (aka outside the grid) -> At least not correct as the method is only called 185 times.
2. The cells are calculated to be outside the grid therefore not tried to be rendered by the UICollectionView -> Still possible as I couldn't figure how to proof that.
3. There is a (if so hopefully configurable) maximum amount of elements the UICollectionView can draw and 31x8 already exceeds that number -> Still possible couldn't find anything about that.

So summary:

Is it possible to display all elements in the grid (32x64 max) and if so, what is wrong in my implementation?

Thank you all for your time and answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing a whole lot of calculating that you don't need to do. Also, setting the `.frame` of a cell is a really bad idea. One big point of a collection view is to *avoid* having to set frames.

Take a look at this:

```
class GridCollectionViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var theCV: UICollectionView!

    var numCols = 0
    var numRows = 0

    func updateCV() -> Void {

        // subtract the number of colums (for the 1-pt spacing between cells), and divide by number of columns
        let w = (theCV.frame.size.width - CGFloat((numCols - 1))) / CGFloat(numCols)

        // subtract the number of rows (for the 1-pt spacing between rows), and divide by number of rows
        let h = (theCV.frame.size.height - CGFloat((numRows - 1))) / CGFloat(numRows)

        // get the smaller of the two values
        let wh = min(w, h)

        // set the cell size
        if let layout = theCV.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: wh, height: wh)
        }

        // reload the collection view
        theCV.reloadData()

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        // start with a 31x20 grid, just to see it
        numCols = 31
        numRows = 20

        updateCV()
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return numRows
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return numCols
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = theCV.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        return cell
    }

    @IBAction func btnTap(_ sender: Any) {
        // example of changing the number of rows/columns based on user action
        numCols = 32
        numRows = 64
        updateCV()
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi,

thank you very much, first of all this is a nice solution!
I wasn't aware of the layout.itemSize property so that's very helpful.

I kept my calculation of the size as the one you provided resulted in the last square always drawn into it's own row. So it was 16 rows when I put 31x8 where every second row just had one square and the others 7.

Anyway this helped me find a good solution and clean up my code + learning something new, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to develop your own [UICollectionViewLayout](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout). With this approach you can achieve any result human being can imagine.

```
import UIKit

class CollectionLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    private var width: Int = 1
    private var height: Int = 1

    func set(width: Int, height: Int) {
        guard width > 0, height > 0 else { return }

        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        calculateItemSize()
    }

    private func calculateItemSize() {
        guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return }
        let size = collectionView.frame.size
        var itemWidth = size.width / CGFloat(width)
        // spacing is needed only if there're more than 2 items in a row
        if width > 1 {
            itemWidth -= minimumInteritemSpacing
        }
        var itemHeight = size.height / CGFloat(height)
        if height > 1 {
            itemHeight -= minimumLineSpacing
        }
        let edgeLength = min(itemWidth, itemHeight)
        itemSize = CGSize(width: edgeLength, height: edgeLength)
    }

    // calculate origin for every item
    override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath)

        // calculate item position in the grid
        let col = CGFloat(indexPath.row % width)
        let row = CGFloat(Int(indexPath.row / width))

        // don't forget to take into account 'minimumInteritemSpacing' and 'minimumLineSpacing'
        let x = col * itemSize.width + col * minimumInteritemSpacing
        let y = row * itemSize.height + row * minimumLineSpacing

        // set new origin
        attributes?.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)

        return attributes
    }

    // accumulate all attributes
    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        guard let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect) else { return nil }
        var newAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
        for attribute in attributes {
            if let newAttribute = layoutAttributesForItem(at: attribute.indexPath) {
                newAttributes.append(newAttribute)
            }
        }
        return newAttributes
    }
}
```

Set our layout to UICollectionView

[image]

Update collection view every time user enters width and height:

```
@IBAction func onSetTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    width = Int(widthTextField.text!)
    height = Int(heightTextField.text!)
    if let width = width, let height = height,
       let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? CollectionLayout {
        layout.set(width: width, height: height)
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```